# make 1 button do two different function in controller php codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

i have one button in my form which supposed to insert the data into database and send the data as an email. so my question is can i separate the function in controller? i already tried to put both (insert into database and sending the data as an email) in only one function. it really looked messed up since the function i actually wanted to do is more than those 2. 
`public function insertdata(){...}` 
and `public function sendemail(){...}`
maybe something like that.

Comment: Yes, of course, make as many methods as you need, and call them from the one linked to the route

Comment: you can add a second button in your from, both buttons need to has a name, and in your controller first you need to catch chat button the user make click and then make you logic. Or in your second button use the html5 action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course,  this is possible. You create two functions using the first function insert data and check your data will be inserted or not. If inserted then call the second function and send your mail. For example:

```
public function insertdata(){
   $data = $this->input->post();
   //add model
   $result = $this->insert_model->InsertData($data);
   if($result>0){
     $this->sendmail($data);
   }else{
     $this->session->set_flashdata('Your data not inserted');
   }
}
public function sendmail($data){
   //here you can read data and write code for send email.
}
```

Comment: This will work but it's not best practice for CodeIgniter to call one function from within another like that.  The `sendmail` function in the example above should be made into a Library.  See:  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: Sparky you are absolutely write, you can create library for email and call into sendmail function.